# slf4j logger.info how to NOT print out the package information

Tags: log4j, logback, slf4j, log4j2

let say I have this code:

```
public static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());
public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOGGER.info("Hi !");
    }
```

But the output in console is this:

```
[main] INFO com.sirma.itt.javacourse.logger.example - Hi !
```

I would like to customize or edit the output. I do not need this "package information". So it would looks like this:

```
[main] - Hi !
```

or just:

```
Hi !
```

Comment: Could you please add your log configuration file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I did:
**1**. In parent pom I switched the defauld slf4j dependency with:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.13</version>
</dependency>
```

**2**. In src/main/resources I created a file with name logback.xml and enter these settings:

```
    <configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%thread] %-5level - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="deng" level="DEBUG" />

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

it's related with the pattern in your log4j or logback properties.

In log4j, leave that only with "%m%n", you can get a output "HI !".

see https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html

https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html